# Serializable class not restoring state

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

**HUMAN ERROR. THE CODE BELOW DOES NOT HAVE ERROR**

Moderators: Please remove this. If possible, please send 25 of my reputation to Peter Lawrey as he has helped me a lot, even reading through thick stacks of log data. Thanks!

Hi I'm having trouble with a Serializable database.

After closing the program (through the logout button), the database is supposed to be stored. This is the code:

```
FileOutputStream f_out = null;
        try {
            f_out = new FileOutputStream("database.data");
            ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream(f_out);
            obj_out.writeObject(database);
            System.out.println("Stored!");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BankMainFrameGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } finally {
            try {
                f_out.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BankMainFrameGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        new BankMainFrameGUI();
        this.dispose();
```

The database is then restored upon login with this code:

```
    try {
        FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream("database.data");
        ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream(f_in);
        database = (BankSystem) obj_in.readObject();
        System.out.println("FOUND!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("New database!");
        database = new BankSystem();
    }
```

The database and all its internal classes have been set to be serializable. However, upon restarting the program, all data is lost (of clients, accounts, transactions). However, the database is still detected as a "Found!" statement is shown in my compiler's CLI, but not the "New database!" statement.

I used both linked lists and array lists.

Thank you so much! I will up-rate all workable solutions.

**SPOILER: LOTS OF POSSIBLY UNNECESSARY INFORMATION**

**Extra information if required:**

```
Main BankSystem() constructor + important variables:

public class BankSystem implements Serializable {
    Transaction transactionManager;
    Identity identityManager;
    Account accountManager;
    dayFirstTransaction dayFirstTransactionManager;


    public BankSystem() {
        transactionManager = new Transaction();
        identityManager = new Identity();
        accountManager = new Account();
        dayFirstTransactionManager = new dayFirstTransaction();
    }
...
```

Example of a LinkedList node:

```
class Transaction implements Serializable { //Database for TransactionNode
    TransactionNode lastTransaction = null;
    long lastTransactionId = -1;

    //Unchangable location settings defined. Prevents ability to manipulate timestamp by changing computer clock. Acts as a security feature.
    //Timestamps are also finalised to ensure security (prevent manipulation)
    final TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Singapore");
    final Locale lc = new Locale("en", "SG");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS EEEE");
    final private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz, lc);

    public long newTransaction(dayFirstTransaction dFTM,
            Client identity, AccountNode account, boolean action, long actionAmount, 
            String location, String comments) throws IOException {
        //Setting timings
        long timeMilli = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

        TransactionNode previous = lastTransaction;
        TransactionNode previousUserTransaction = account.GetLastTransaction();

        long transactionId = ++lastTransactionId;

        long initialBalance = account.getBalance();
        long finalBalance;
        if(action) {
            finalBalance = initialBalance + actionAmount;
        } else {
            if(initialBalance < actionAmount) throw new IOException("There is not enough funds present in account " + account.accountId + ". \nAvailable balance: $" + account.getBalance());
            finalBalance = initialBalance - actionAmount;
        }

        lastTransaction = new TransactionNode(previous, previousUserTransaction, timeMilli, timeStamp,  
            transactionId, identity, account, action, actionAmount, 
            initialBalance, finalBalance, location, comments);

        dFTM.checkTransaction(lastTransaction);
        account.setLastTransaction(lastTransaction);
        return transactionId;
    }

        public void newTransaction (dayFirstTransaction dFTM, long timeMilli, String timeStamp,  
            Client identity, AccountNode account, boolean action, long actionAmount, 
            long initialBalance, long finalBalance, String location, String comments) throws IOException {

        TransactionNode previous = lastTransaction;
        TransactionNode previousUserTransaction = account.GetLastTransaction();

        long transactionId = ++lastTransactionId;

        lastTransaction = new TransactionNode(previous, previousUserTransaction, timeMilli, timeStamp,  
            transactionId, identity, account, action, actionAmount, 
            initialBalance, finalBalance, location, comments);

        dFTM.checkTransaction(lastTransaction);
        account.setLastTransaction(lastTransaction);
    }
...
```

And the node for this linked list:

```
class TransactionNode implements Serializable {
    //Node direction pointers
    final private TransactionNode previous;
    final private TransactionNode previousUserTransaction;

    //Declarations
    //For action:
    final public boolean CREDIT = true;
    final public boolean DEBIT = false;

    //Variables for each transaction
    final public long timeMilli; //Automated. For time comparisons
    final public String timeStamp;//Automated. For user reference
    final public long transactionId; // Automated at Transaction LinkedList
    final public Client identity;
    final public AccountNode account;
    final public boolean action; //true: Credit. false:Debit
    final public long actionAmount;
    final public long initialBalance;
    final public long finalBalance;
    final public String location;
    final public String comments;

    public TransactionNode(TransactionNode previous, TransactionNode previousUserTransaction, long timeMilli, String timeStamp,  
            long transactionId, Client identity, AccountNode account, boolean action, long actionAmount, 
            long initialBalance, long finalBalance, String location, String comments) {
        this.previous = previous;
        this.previousUserTransaction = previousUserTransaction;
        this.timeMilli = timeMilli;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.identity = identity;
        this.account = account;
        this.action = action;
        this.actionAmount = actionAmount;
        this.initialBalance = initialBalance;
        this.finalBalance = finalBalance;
        this.location = location;
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    //Getters & setters
    public TransactionNode getPreviousTransaction() {
        return previous;
    }

    public TransactionNode getPreviousUserTransaction() {
        return previousUserTransaction;
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: This is my code, so I will be able to provide my whole source code if required. I just do not want to spam this page with long lists of code.

Comment: (I'd just like to point out that your resource management is broken. Always use the form `acquire(); try { use(); } finally { release(); }`, or with the current version of Java SE `try (Resource resource = acquire()) { use(); }`. Pretty much everyone messes up when trying to do something cunning with `null`s. Often repeatedly. In this case, an exception when acquiring the resource causes the release code to NPE.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Is it possible that you provide a code snipplet? `ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("database.data"));` requires me to surround it with try&catch.

Comment: Don't force the same `try` to do two different jobs. `try { final FileOutputStream f_out = new FileOutputStream("database.data"); try { ... } finally { f_out.close(); } catch (IOException exc) { ... "handle" exception ... }` Or in Java SE 7, `try (final FileOutputStream f_out = new FileOutputStream("database.data")) { ... } catch (IOException exc) { ... "handle" exception ... }`

Comment: alright, Thanks! I have done that but no error is being thrown

Comment: I'm SOOOO sorry guys. I initialised a new database somewhere else, and I can't believe I spent 3 hours on solving it. I would like to thank all of you for trying as well, especially @PeterLawrey for helping me out soo much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you are not closing the stream you wrote to.  ObjectOutputStream is buffered and if you close the file it is writing to instead of closing it, you won't have written all the data and when you try to read it you will get an exception.

Comment: I assume you're recommending me to append `obj_out.close()` before `f_out.close()`? Unfortunately the problem still persists

Comment: You only need `object_out.close()` Can you clarify what the problem is? You must be doing something very wrong some of the classes or collections are different before and after serialisation.

Comment: the database is still detected as a "Found!" statement is shown in my compiler's CLI, but not the "New database!" statement. However, the information inside the database is all gone.

Comment: Sorry, I also do not get what you mean by "some of the classes or collections are different before and after serialisation". The code is not changed in between the logout-login sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by "all gone" specifically? Do you mean the lists are empty even though they are not when you serialized them? Do you mean the lists are not empty but they full of `null` or that the accounts are there but they are full of `0` and `null` etc.

Comment: I mean; is the contents of the collections not the same?

Comment: Where are your lists defined? Can you provide the code for that data structure (i.e. for the ones which actually fail ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15600/discussion-between-pipng13579-and-peter-lawrey)

Comment: I marked this as the answer because Peter helped me the most. This error was caused due to a stupid oversight on another piece of code. SORRY GUYS!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not triggering this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("New database!");
   database = new BankSystem();
}
```

I would *at least* print out the exception and stack trace associated with the above, even if it's not being triggered.

I would also check that the file you write out is being created, and is a non-zero size. That will give you some indicator as to if the data is being written (beware - perhaps incompletely) or not being read.

Comment: I get "FOUND!" everytime though, and never "New database!". So I don't think it's the issue.

Comment: @pipng13579 In that case, can you clarify what you mean by "all data is lost" as it appears it passed your "test"?

Comment: When I try to create a new account (using a previously created client), an error appears stating that that account is not available ONLY if the client was created on a different run from the account. This issue is also seen when writing a new transaction with a pre-existing account

Answer (score 1):

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("New database!");
    database = new BankSystem();
}
```

Here's a major problem. This is a ridiculous way to handle a deserialization exception. Instead of logging the actual exception and aborting, you are:

1. *Completely ignoring* the actual exception, which is the *only* source of information as to what actually went wrong.
2. Proceeding as though nothing had happened.
3. Proceeding with an empty database rather than a null database, which is letting the rest of your application continue as though nothing had gone wrong at all except a mysteriously zeroed database.

I wouldn't even catch that exception at all. I would let it bubble up all the way through the constructors and possibly even the `main()` method.

Comment: I did so as this as a project to be submitted. As such, the teacher may accidentally remove the database file. In such as case, I want the system to assume it was initiated from scratch. Furthermore, a 'New database!' statement would show in the compiler's CLI, so I know what happened.

Comment: @pipng13579 And that is exactly what has happened, so what are you complaining about? You should *at least* have logged the actual exception. Without that, debugging this problem is just a guessing game.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have made myself clear. The CLI reads "FOUND!" but all the data is not initialised after the system was closed and reopened

Comment: I have edited the question to make that point clearer. Sorry!

Comment: @pipng13579 The moral remains, whether or not this is the actual site of the problem. *Never* ignore an exception. There are a very few obvious exceptions. This isn't one of them.

Comment: I have since added a Log. The solution is unfortunately still not solved

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the streams
2. Ensure every class implements `serializable`  Few classes which are not visible to us `Client`, `AccountNode`
3. Use printStackTrace() method in each exception.

Comment: I have closed all my streams, and ensured that all classes implement serializable. Also, exceptions are thrown, and are all caught by `JOptionPane s` that show the error message. Despite all this, the database cannot be restored.